# Curve Tracing: Why I'm getting asymptotes parallel to both X & Y Axis?

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves

Here is equation of curve.
$ x^2 y^2=a ^2 (y ^2- x^2) $

Here is my calculations...tell me if something is wrong in it.
[My Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A048C.jpg)

Comment: Because they both exist.

Comment: How can that exist??

Comment: Both on x & y axis??

Comment: We can't even draw such curve...

Comment: You should write out your calculations in MathJaX. As a sidenote the equality $-a^2 = y^2$ has no real solutions.

Comment: @Triatticus ooooppps!!! Yaa.....thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for $x^2$ and $y^2$ we have

$$
x^2 = \frac{a^2 y^2}{a^2+ y^2}\\
y^2 = \frac{a^2 x^2}{a^2-x^2}
$$

In the first, we have

$$
\lim_{y\to\infty} x^2 = a^2
$$

and in the second

$$
\lim_{x_{\pm}\to \pm a} = \pm\infty
$$

so the asymptotes are located at $x = \pm a$

[image]

Comment: Thank You soo much !!!!!!